Failed to start services vmmon, vmnet after installing Ubuntu 16 or Ubuntu 18.04 20.04
Been running into this issue: unable to run vmware workstation 10,11, 12 or later on Ubuntu 16.04 or later. Kernel version seems incompatible. When an attempt is made to run the program after installing it, you get errors saying that it cannot start services vmmon and vmnet because files are needed to compile it into the kernel modules.

be aware that versions 16.xx & 18.xx of Ubuntu are EOL

After spending a few hours I finally came across a kb article at vmware that addresses the matter. Sorry for previous dead link. Since Broadcom took vmware - all support links are hidden.
However the kb article suggests a series of steps with commands that do execute successfully. However upon reboot, ..the error returns.
So for me the fix did not work. Whether I start vmware from the command line or GUI, I get the error: "before you run vmware, certain modules must be compiled and started...click to install them..."
I click the install button. And then comes the error, cannot start vmmon, vmnet, services..modules missing. (Paraphrased).
The fix: install modules and  make a self signed Openssl key that allows the system to load the vmmon and vmnet drivers....as they are unsigned...and the Ubuntu 16.04 or later does not allow unsigned drivers to be loaded.
Vmware (now Broadcom) claim that you don't have to turn off your secure boot option.
As I said the error returned. There are no patches available from vmware for this issue. Here is some of the text from vmware kb article. Doing these steps worked for me.
///////BEGIN##
Workstation does not ship vmmon.ko and vmnet.ko in the bundle currently. The two modules are built during the installation or the first launch of workstation.
During the installation if the host provides the proper kernel headers and gcc, these two modules will be built silently. The progress is logged into /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-PID.log.
When workstation is first launched, a dialog will pop up to ask you for the usable kernel headers and/or gcc. These two modules will be built with window showing the progress and log printed on terminal.
To correct the issue with secure boot enabled:
Generate a key pair using the openssl to sign vmmon and vmnet modules:
$openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"
Replace MOK with the name of the file you want for the key.
Sign the modules using the generated key by running these commands:
$sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-uname -r/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)
$sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-uname -r/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)
Import the public key to the system's MOK list by running this command:
$mokutil --import MOK.der
Confirm a password for this MOK enrollment request.
Reboot your machine. Follow the instructions to complete the enrollment from the UEFI console.
///////END#
ANOTHER FIX:
Kudos to @St3rven at github for this fix at the link.
https://gist.github.com/st3rven/1c76ff2954481e5c95cb361ea0c856a2
